# javaScript increment and decrement

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

Supernewbie question but something i cant get and i hope you guys clear it out when i run this code i get
as a result in the console the loop shows:

```js
var x = 2
var y = 4
var x = 4
var y = 2
var x = 5
var y = 1

function myFunction() {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 5;
    var z = 5;
    while (x < z) {
        x++;
        y--;
        if (x == y) {
            continue;
        }
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
    }
}
myFunction();
```

why in the first instances the loop increase by 1 like the code its commanding on x but in the second instance its increasing and decreasing by double but then in the third time the loop its run its back to just add 1 and decrease 1, i really dont get it,I hope someone can clear out this question, thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: You are doing `x == y continue` before the console log, which means that when x = 3, y = 3 too so you skip the logging part in this iteration. You are still looping 4 times.

Comment: Like what @Karl-AndréGagnon said, and you are increasing x and decreasing y before logging, so it doesn't log when x is 1 and y is 5.
Combine both logs into one: `console.log("x="+x+", y="+y)`.

Comment: btw, you can do `x === y` and it would be (minisculely) faster because the double equal sign (`==`) means that the type of the values does not matter, therefore it has to do a couple of checks for different types, unlike the type-specific triple equal sign (`===`).  For example, `1 == "1"` returns true, but `1 === "1"` returns false

Comment: thank you so much guys!!! great help now its cleared. have a good weekend!!!